# Code completion with antlr4-c3: getting recursive scope

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, antlr4, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am trying to use the code completion with antlr4-c3.

Suppose that the list of suggestions for the function argument depends on the function's name. So for the following expression

```
foo(bar(...))
```

I want to get a list of ["foo", "bar"] so that I can perform autocompletion where the dots are.

Here is the grammar example:

```
grammar Scope;

expression:
      function
    | INT
;


function:
    NAME '(' expression ')'
;

NAME: [a-z]+;
INT:  [0-9]+;
WS:        [ \n\r\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

This is my attempt to get this information:

```
        const inputStream = CharStreams.fromString("foo(bar(123))");
        const lexer = new ScopeLexer(inputStream);
        const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

        const parser = new ScopeParser(tokenStream);
        const errorListener = new ErrorListener();
        parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);
        parser.expression();

        const core = new c3.CodeCompletionCore(parser);

        core.preferredRules = new Set([ScopeParser.RULE_function]);

        const candidates = core.collectCandidates(5);

        console.log("=================== rules ======================");
        for (const [key, value] of candidates.rules) {
            console.log(key, value);
            let functions = candidates.rules.get(ScopeParser.RULE_function)?.ruleList;
            console.log(functions);
        }
```

but all it returns is this:

```
=================== rules ======================
1 { startTokenIndex: 0, ruleList: [ 0 ] }
[ 0 ]
```

Any suggestions how to get the list of function names?

If I turn on the debug information

```
        core.showDebugOutput=true;
        core.showRuleStack=true;
```

I could see that the stack of functions I am looking for was created internally, but then the stack is unwound before returning the candidate object.

```
<0> Current state: [0 rule start] in expression
expression
<0> Current state: [6 block start] in expression
expression
<0> Current state: [5 basic] in expression
expression
<0> Current state: [4 basic] in expression
expression
  <0> Current state: [2 rule start] in function
expression
function
  <0> Current state: [8 basic] in function
expression
function
=====> consumed:  NAME
  <1> Current state: [9 basic] in function
expression
function
=====> consumed:  '('
  <2> Current state: [10 basic] in function
expression
function
    <2> Current state: [0 rule start] in expression
expression
function
expression
    <2> Current state: [6 block start] in expression
expression
function
expression
    <2> Current state: [5 basic] in expression
expression
function
expression
    <2> Current state: [4 basic] in expression
expression
function
expression
      <2> Current state: [2 rule start] in function
expression
function
expression
function
      <2> Current state: [8 basic] in function
expression
function
expression
function
=====> consumed:  NAME
      <3> Current state: [9 basic] in function
expression
function
expression
function
=====> consumed:  '('
      <4> Current state: [10 basic] in function
expression
function
expression
function
        <4> Current state: [0 rule start] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
        <4> Current state: [6 block start] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
        <4> Current state: [5 basic] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
=====> consumed:  INT
        <<5>> Current state: [7 block end] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
        <<5>> Current state: [1 rule stop] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
        <4> Current state: [4 basic] in expression
expression
function
expression
function
expression
      <<5>> Current state: [11 basic] in function
expression
function
expression
function
=====> collected:  function
```

PS. The original problem originated from JSONPath grammar. Within filters, I need to build the list of names. The list is determined by the absolute path up to this point.

Comment: Have you tried with smaller token indexes? Position 5 is the closing par in your test input. Not sure what could be shown at this position.

Comment: @
Yes, I tried different token positions with the same result. 
@MikeLischke Maybe I just do not understand what `candidate.rules` stand for. I am trying to get the parser invocation stack at the given token index, keeping only some grammar rules. (the ones which would affect the combined symbol table)

PS. Thank you for writing the tool!

Comment: As described in the readme the rules member contains a list of rule indexes. These are the same what is listed in your generated parser (e.g. `RULE_expression`).Do you get any numbers in this list when invoking the engine?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a single rule.

Comment: Based on https://tomassetti.me/code-completion-with-antlr4-c3/ the rules field is not a stack of the rules (as I thought) but the rules to be expected at the given token index.